# jquery.remove() function won't work properly in IE7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I've following structure in HTML

```
<ul class="nav">
<li><a href="...">NA</a></li>
<li class="bottomup">
    <a href="..." >A</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="...">B</a></li>
        <li><a href="...">C</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="bottomup">
    <a href="..." >X</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="...">Y</a></li>
        <li><a href="...">Z</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

and the requirement is if the user clicks on `NA`, `A` or `X` then the siblings of these items are made hidden and if they have a sublist (e.g. `A`, `X`) then only that is displayed with anchor tag added in an LI at the top of the immediate sub-list. So if I click on A then result should be

```
<ul class="nav">
<li><a href="...">NA</a></li> //hidden
<li>
    <a href="..." >A</a> //hidden
    <ul>
        <li><a href="...">A</a></li>
        <li><a href="...">B</a></li>
        <li><a href="...">C</a></li>
    </ul>
</li> //hidden
<li>// hidden
    <a href="..." >X</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="...">Y</a></li>
        <li><a href="...">Z</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

To achieve this I cloned the anchor tag and added in the immediate UL inside the LI and removed the anchor tag using `.remove()` (tried `.hide()` as well instead of remove). Problem is that the anchor tag as well as LI have some css with padding and background image. In all browsers it works fine but in IE when I inspect I see border of lis perfectly aligned w.r.t to UL but the anchor tag is dis-placed by few pixels from the top and no css fix is solving this. Please help.

Please note, on click "open" class gets added to the selected LI and 'selected' class gets added to the anchor.

JavaScript code is :

```
var topDownItems = $('div#main_nav ul.nav').find('.open');
if(topDownItems.length>0){
    for(var i=0;i<topDownItems.length;i++){
        var item = $(topDownItems)[i];
        var classname = $(item).attr('class');
        if(classname=='bottomup open'){             
            $("<li />").append($(item).children('a').clone()).prependTo($(item).children('ul'));
            $(item).children('a').remove();
            $(item).children('ul').each(function(){
                $(this).children('li').each(function(){
                    $(this).find('ul').each(function(){
                        $(this).hide();
                    });
                });
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks,
Asha

Comment: The actual JavaScript code would be even more interesting that the HTML.  Also the CSS.  Ideally, a jsfiddle example.

Comment: $(item).children('a').html(""); // instead of .remove() ? I cant get your code to work.  I assume you have a more in depth environment.